# How to figure out what is the project type of an application?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am using Subclipse with Eclipse to check out java project from our repository. When checking out the project, Subclipse asks me to identify which project type it is, so that eclipse can best present it to me. I am wondering if there is any rule of thumb to follow to figure that out? As most of the files in repositories, the project definition file is not backed up in the repository.

Comment: Ask whoever originally shared the project. :-)  A better way would be to have separate directories in Subversion for the various project types.  Finally, you can guess based on the directory structure of the application.  An Eclipse plug-in will have certain directories and a Java project will have certain directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are any general rules of thumb, but experience would be a huge factor. Knowing something about the project or looking at the source should help narrow down your choices. Doing this should answer these questions: language? type of project (webapp, library, desktop app, etc)?. Ask to find out what other developers are doing or have done (with that particular code base). If all else fails trial and error would work too.

A note on IDE files in version control: I personally don't believe in doing it. See [this](http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2012/07/ide-project-files-in-version-contro-yes.html).